# Basic button with title, subtitle and icon using boostrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap and would like to keep it so (no further libraries for now). I have a couple of buttons on a webpage, something like

```
|----------------------|
|       (icon)         |
|   BIG TITLE HERE     |
|  Small subtitle here |
|----------------------|

|----------------------|
|       (icon)         |
|   BIG TITLE HERE     |
|  Small subtitle here |
|----------------------|
```

They're located on the left side of the page on a div of 3 columns (col-md-3). So far I have this block of HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <ul class="buttons-ue">
            <li class="bg-lh text-uppercase bg-warning text-warning">
                <i class="icon-warning"></i>
                <strong>Title 1</strong>
                <small>Press here for warning</small>
            </li>
            <li class="bg-lh text-uppercase bg-danger text-danger">
                <i class="icon-danger"></i>
                <strong>Title 2</strong>
                <small>Press here if you dare</small>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

and a couple of css class yet to improve

```
.buttons-ue {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    list-style: none;
}
.bg-lh {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 5px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 90%;
    padding: 10px 0;
    position: relative;
}
.icon-danger {}
.icon-warning {}
```

What is the proper approach, css speaking, to build this kind of component so I simply plug in a couple more in the future.

Comment: If there are only a few instances where the code is going to run you could have custom page specific CSS were the code only runs on those specific pages. Otherwise create a global CSS file that runs on all the pages so no matter where you add the button it will have the styling it needs.

Comment: I'm actually looking for some tips on how to build that component in terms of CSS good practices, using bootstrap and as least additional style as possible. For instance, the icon image, should I use src directly on a  HTML tag or define the background on CSS class?